# Why is this deleting all of my items in the array at once? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a CV builder which the user can input information such as the company, date, title, location and it gets saved inside an array when the user presses the save button. Then, that array is rendered in HTML form with a remove button.

I want that remove button to only delete one item of an array. For example, if we create two companies I've worked on it would create a remove button for both of them [image: And it would look like this]

I want that when we click the remove button once, not all the items of the array gets deleted which is what my code is currently doing. I can't figure out a logic to perform this and I've only tried this filter method but it deletes all of the items...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import '../styles/style.css'

const Experience = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({title: "", company: "", date: "", location: "", description: ""})
  const [result, setResult] = useState([])


  const togglePopup = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }

  const saveForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setResult(result.concat(input))
  }
  const removeItems = (data) => {
      setResult(result.filter(todo => todo.title === data.title));
  }
console.log(result)

    return(
      <ul>
      <button onClick={togglePopup}>Work Experience</button>
      {result.map((data) => (
        <>
        <p key={data.title}>{data.title}</p>
        <p>{data.company}</p>
        <p>{data.date}</p>
        <p>{data.location}</p>
        <p>{data.description}</p>
        <button onClick={removeItems}>Remove</button>
        </>
      ))}
      {toggle && <form>
        <div>
          <label>Job Title</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input value={input.title} onChange={ e => {setInput({ title: e.target.value }) }}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Company</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input onChange={ e => {setInput({...input, company: e.target.value }) }}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Date Worked (MM/YYYY - MM/YYYY)</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input onChange={ e => {setInput({...input, date: e.target.value }) }}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Location (e.g. Los Angeles, CA)</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input onChange={ e => {setInput({...input, location: e.target.value }) }}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input onChange={ e => {setInput({...input, description: e.target.value }) }}/>
        </div>

        <button onClick={saveForm}>Save</button>
        <button onClick={togglePopup}>Cancel</button>
       </form>}
     </ul>
    )
  }

export default Experience
```

Comment: instead of  "<button onClick={removeItems}>Remove</button>"  try this 

"<button onClick={() => removeItems(data.title)}>Remove</button>"

Comment: no parameter is being passed to removeItems function

Comment: Without passing the title into the remove function, how are you planning on deleting the item from the correct list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass particular object to match and remove like-

```
<button onClick={() => removeItems(data)}>Remove</button>
```

Improved:

```
  {result.map((data) => (
      <>
        <p key={data.title}>{data.title}</p>
        <p>{data.company}</p>
        <p>{data.date}</p>
        <p>{data.location}</p>
        <p>{data.description}</p>
        <button onClick={() => removeItems(data)}>Remove</button>
      </>
   ))}
```

function -> remove particular which is clicked.

```
const removeItems = (data) => {
      const updated = result.filter(todo => todo.title !== data.title)
      setResult([...updated]);
  }
```